# How to convert python to 100% pyspark?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs 
from pyspark.sql import types as T, SparkSession
```

Here I create an array with sklearn and pure python. This array has two columns with float type values.

```
X, labels_true = make_blobs(
    n_samples=750, centers=centers, 
    cluster_std=0.4, random_state=5
)
```

Then I use loops to format the data and create an id.

```
data = [
    (i, [float(item) for item in X[i]]) 
    for i in range(X.shape[0])
]
```

Then I define a schema, which has the id and an array of floats containing the two columns generated by make_blobs. And I turn it into dataframe spark.

```
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType(), False),
    T.StructField("value", T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()), False)
]) 

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).repartition(10)
```

If instead of generating the data array with make_blobs, I had a spark dataframe with the same information, how to get the same final result?

How to run the code below in a pyspark dataframe?

```
data = [
    (i, [float(item) for item in X[i]]) 
    for i in range(X.shape[0])
]
```

Comment: What does your df currently look like and what do you want it to be? Is it simply adding an index column?

Comment: make_blobs generates a numpy array with two columns of type float. Then I transform these two columns into an array, the two elements of type float, in addition to an id field. There are two columns (id, value [item a, item b]). This process is done in python. But assuming now it's not a numpy array generated by make_blobs but a pyspark dataframe, how to do the same thing?